# Application wide Modal in React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-modal

I'm currently using [react native modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) and it serves the purpose of showing modals.

My problem currently is that I want to show the modal application wide. For example when a push notification received I want to invoke the modal regardless of which screen user is in. The current design of the modals bind it to a single screen.

How can this be overcome?

Comment: if possible could you share your code..

Answer (score 0):

first of all make a context of your modal

```js
const BottomModal = React.createContext();
```

then provide your modal using reactcontext provider

```js
export const BottomModalProvider = ({children}) => {
  const panelRef = useRef();
  const _show = useCallback((data, type) => {
    panelRef.current.show();
  }, []);

  const _hide = useCallback(() => {
    panelRef.current.hide();
  }, []);



  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      _show,
      _hide,
    };
  }, [_hide, _show]);

  return (
    <BottomPanelContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      <BottomPanel fixed ref={panelRef} />
    </BottomPanelContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

here is code for bottom panel

```js
function BottomPanel(props, ref) {
  const {fixed} = props;
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const _hide = () => {
    !fixed && hideModal();
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setVisibility(false);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    show: () => {
      setVisibility(true);
    },
    hide: () => {
      hideModal();
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Modal
      // swipeDirection={["down"]}
      hideModalContentWhileAnimating
      isVisible={visible}
      avoidKeyboard={true}
      swipeThreshold={100}
      onSwipeComplete={() => _hide()}
      onBackButtonPress={() => _hide()}
      useNativeDriver={true}
      style={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        margin: 0,
      }}>
      <Container style={[{flex: 0.9}]}>
        {!fixed ? (
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            <Button
              style={{marginBottom: 10}}
              color={'white'}
              onPress={() => setVisibility(false)}>
              OK
            </Button>
          </View>
        ) : null}
        {props.renderContent && props.renderContent()}
      </Container>
    </Modal>
  );
}

BottomPanel = forwardRef(BottomPanel);

export default BottomPanel;
```

then wrap your app using the provider

```js
...
  <BottomModalProvider>
          <NavigationContainer screenProps={screenProps} theme={theme} />
  </BottomModalProvider>
...
```

lastly how to show or hide modal
provide a custom hook

```
const useBottomPanel = props => {
  return useContext(BottomPanelContext);
};
```

use it anywhere in app like

```js
  const {_show, _hide} = useBottomModal();
   //....
   openModal=()=> {
     _show(); 
   }
  //...
```

If you are not using hooks or using class components
you can easily convert hooks with class context

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

this way  you can achieve only showing the modal from within components
another way is store the panel reference globally anywhere and use that reference to show hide from non-component files like redux or notification cases.